# Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: Unknown helper objectSpread2 at loadHelper

Tags: node.js, react, mobile, react-native

Estou desenvolvendo uma app no react native. Contudo ao gerar o buildo recebo estar  mensagem:

> Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed:
>   ReferenceError: Unknown helper objectSpread2
>       at loadHelper

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Looking for JS files in
>   C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon
>
> Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed:
>   ReferenceError: Unknown helper objectSpread2
>       at loadHelper (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\helpers\lib\index.js:238:27)
>       at Object.getDependencies (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\helpers\lib\index.js:279:21)
>       at File.addHelper (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\file\file.js:204:33)
>       at PluginPass.addHelper (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\core\lib\transformation\plugin-pass.js:31:22)
>       at PluginPass.ObjectExpression (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:379:25)
>       at newFn (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:193:21)
>       at NodePath._call (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
>       at NodePath.call (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
>       at NodePath.visit (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)
>   DELTA  [android, dev] ....../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 56.4%
>   (389/518)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2019:00:07:27 +0000] "GET
>   /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"  DELTA  [android, dev] ....../index.js
>   ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 56.4% (389/518), failed.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outra mensagem de erro:**

> The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> URL:
>   http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
>
> Body:
>   {"type":"TransformError","lineNumber":0,"errors":[{"description":"node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\ActivityIndicator\ActivityIndicator.js:
>   Unknown helper
>   objectSpread2","lineNumber":0}],"name":"SyntaxError","message":"node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\ActivityIndicator\ActivityIndicator.js:
>   Unknown helper objectSpread2","stack":"ReferenceError: Unknown helper
>   objectSpread2\n    at loadHelper
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\helpers\lib\index.js:238:27)\n
>   at Object.getDependencies
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\helpers\lib\index.js:279:21)\n
>   at File.addHelper
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\file\file.js:204:33)\n
>   at PluginPass.addHelper
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\plugin-pass.js:31:22)\n
>   at PluginPass.ObjectExpression
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:379:25)\n
>   at newFn
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:193:21)\n
>   at NodePath._call
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)\n
>   at NodePath.call
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)\n
>   at NodePath.visit
>   (C:\Users\sulwork01\Documents\react-native\rn-WhoIsThisPokemon\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)"}
>   processBundleResult
>       BundleDownloader.java:296 access$200
>       BundleDownloader.java:37 onResponse
>       BundleDownloader.java:174 execute
>       RealCall.java:206 run
>       NamedRunnable.java:32 runWorker
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162 run
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636 run
>       Thread.java:764

**Versão do React-Native**
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui corrigi apagando a pasta node_modules, logo apos reinstalei com npm install e restartando o package: npm start

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]